# Need help creating a view on top of a JOIN query that needs to return only the latest value

Tags: oracle, join, left-join, oracle12c

I need help with my SQL Query I have Two tables that i need to join using a LEFT OUTER JOIN, then i need to create a database view over that particular view. If i run a query on the join to look for name A i need to get that A's latest brand "AP". 
Table 1

```
ID     name     address
-----------------------  
1      A         ATL
2      B         ATL
```

TABLE 2

```
ID     PER_ID    brand      DATEE
--------------------------------------------
1      1         MS           5/19/17:1:00pm
2      1         XB           5/19/17:1:05pm
3      1         AP           5/19/17:2:00pm
4      2         RO           5/19/17:3:00pm
5      2         WE           5/19/17:4:00pm
```

I tried query a which returns correct result but i get problem 1 when i try to build the database view on top of the join. I tried query b but when i query my view in oracle sql developer i still get all the results but not the latest.

query a:

```
SELECT * from table_1
left outer join table_2 on table_1.ID = Table_2.PER_ID
AND table_2.DATE = (SELECT MAX(DATE) from table_2 z where z.PER_ID = table_2.PER_ID)
```

Problem 1

```
Error report -
ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery
01799. 00000 -  "a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery"
*Cause:    <expression>(+) <relop> (<subquery>) is not allowed.
*Action:   Either remove the (+) or make a view out of the subquery.
           In V6 and before, the (+) was just ignored in this case.
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT * from table_1
    left outer join(SELECT PER_ID,brand, max(DATEE) from table_2 group by brand,PER_ID) t2 on table_1.ID = t2.PER_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.address, t2.id as t2_id, t2.brand, t2.datee
from table_1 t1 left outer join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by per_id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from table_2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.ID = t2.PER_ID and t2.seqnum = 1;
```

When defining a view, you should be in the habit of listing the columns explicitly.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried your code on oracle sql developer, but i now get t2.brand is an invalid qualifier

Comment: just check all the column names and aliases used for each. It is just an error produced when a column reference is incorrect, We cannot debug without access to your tables (or the complete ddl for those tables). ps: I think "order by date desc" should be "order by datee desc") [an "e" is missing]

Comment: thanks, i fixed it. one question i have pertaining to this solution. is it the fastest possible solution? If i wanted to add a table 3,4,5 and do a left outer join on each will i experience lag?

Comment: @stevestark . . . These is a very reasonable solution.  Whether it is the fastest in any particular situation depends on the distribution of values in the data.